Model/API versioning in .NET and propagating the changes to dependent methods
Based on my understanding of the API versioning or model versioning, I see that the model should be updated in this way if there are breaking changes
public class ProductV2 : Product
{
        //New attributes
}

Reference: API Versioning - What do I do if model changes
What if I have a service that uses this model?
public ProcessedProduct ProductProcessService(Product product);

How can I handle the changes in model in the services that are using these models?
The possible options which I see is

Use of an interface

public ProcessedProduct ProductProcessService(IProduct product);


New Method

public ProcessedProduct ProductProcessService(Product product);
public ProcessedProduct ProductProcessServiceV2(ProductV2 product);

Or is there any better way to handle this condition?

Depending on the use case, I would either create v2 of methods in case there aren't major changes or even create separate class to handle for different versions.

I think the 'New Method' you mentioned is a better way to do things.

Use of an interface will just transition the problem you are having to another interface's code.
I would go with second option, separate class to process new Product in version 2. This way "old" handling of product, which is working, will stay untouched and you would prevent any regression in the software.
Plus, new product implementation now can vary and can be adjusted without touching original code for old product.
But, if for old and new product there is majority of implementation common, I would try to put products behind interface (so option number 1) and handle ONLY the differences behind the interface (in the implementation).
